# range of values taken by f(x) based on a range of values for x

Tags: r, function, range

I would like to know the range of values that a function f(x) can take based on a range of values of x.

For instance, say I have a quadratic equation `f(x)=x^2 - x + 0.2` and I want to know the range of f(x) for x in the range [0.2, 1].

is there a function or package in R that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understand your question you are looking for:

```
f <- function(x) x^2 - x + 0.2
x <- seq(0.2, 1, by=0.1)
range(f(x))
# [1]  -0.05  0.20    # approximate numerical answer
```

If you want to know the range in an analytical way you  have to do some mathematics (or further programming) to determine the maximum and minimum of the function `f` in that range of `x`.

Comment: @Pascal  This won't work for non-linear functions which can take values outside the range of the endpoints.  You need `c(min(f(x)),max(f(x)))` which is what `range` does.  The approximate numerical answer is `-0.05, 0.20`.

Answer (score 0):

An analytic answer can be calculated using calculus, if the function is differentiable.  For the example quadratic, the calculation is:

```
f'(x) = 2x -1 = 0   =>   x* =1/2  is argmin/max, and lies within the domain for x: [0.2,1]
Evaluate f at the domain endpoints, and the argmin/max:  
         f(0.2) = 0.04, f(0.5) = -0.05,  f(1) = 0.2.
So min = -0.05, max = 0.2.
```

A numerical approximation will work if the function is well-behaved (e.g. continuous, differentiable).  Otherwise, a spike or discontinuity (e.g. f(x) = 1/x) could be missed depending on the step-size.